# Replace a number in a file in python - script worked and now does not

Tags: python

I need to replace a number in a file for a programme to work. These are ascii files, but don't need to be adapted in format.

The head of the file looks like:

```
 106 106 106 106 106 106 106 106 106 106 106 106 106 106 106 106 106 106 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I want to replace all numbers equal to 106 with -9999 and all numbers equal to 1 to 0.1.

This is my code, which worked previously and now does not:

```
lowres_file = str(lowres_file)

with open(lowres_file, 'r') as f_in:
    with open(lowres_file_converted, 'w') as f_out:
        for line in f_in:
            print(line)
            if line[0] != ' ':
                f_out.write(line)
            else:
                split_line = np.array(line[1:-1].split(' '), dtype = int)
                split_line[split_line == 106] = -9999
                split_line[split_line == 1] = 0.1
                split_line = np.array(split_line, dtype = str)
                new_line = ' ' + ' '.join(split_line) + '\n'
                f_out.write(new_line)
```

However, this doesn't replace the 1s with 0.1, it just replaces them with 0s. Converting the 106 to -9999 works just fine, however.

Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

```
filepointer=open('word.txt','r+')
text=filepointer.read().split(' ')

str_data=''
for i in text:
    if i == '106':
        str_data+='-9999 '
    elif i == '1':
        str_data+='0.1 '

filepointer.close()

filepointer=open('word.txt','w')
filepointer.write(str_data)
```

Comment: Can you offer an explanation? What is your code doing? What was wrong with the original code that you resolved here? That will help the OP and future readers learn.

Comment: @jeremyCaney Hi i gald u asked well i just open a file in read mode and as we know python filepointer returns string in read() function and i split that string space after that i create on variable name str_data and put that split text list in for loop and compare all word with string 106 & 1 if i get true data then i just append -9999 or. 01 according to match and write that string with new file pointer i hope u will understand now. And well i just read question and write my code i have not seen the code above